# How to sum and count elements in view (Rails 4)?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

as I need to count the number of times this loop would execute, can you please tell me which method is for doing `count` in such a situation? And also - the `topicality` is many-to-many field and will display more than one entry, example: `4 8 10 2` I would need to sum and count these and the sum should be divided by their count.

```
<% s.courses.each do |c| %>
   <%= c.skills.topicality %>
   <%= link_to c.title, c %>
<% end %>
```

I hope my explenation made sense, as far as I googled there is `sum` method and `count` method, but none of my attempts to use them had any success.

Can you please show me how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question but I can give a few pointers...

If you want a count of the number of items in a collection it is best to use `.size` 95% of the time in rails. So `s.courses.size` should give you how many courses you have. If you use `.count` you are guaranteed to do another database hit even if it's not needed. Using `.size` will not query the database if the collection has previously been loaded.

If you want to have an index as you loop through the courses you can use `s.courses.each_with_index do |c, index|`. This will track which iteration you're on.

If you want to sum a value in the courses collection you can use `s.courses.sum(:some_attribute)`. This will do the summation in the database. If `topicality` is an array of integers you can sum them with a simple `c.skills.topicality.sum`.